# Performing significant difference tests in endline evaluation

Tags: statistical-significance, survey, proportion, group-differences

we have conducted an endline survey and now comparing the result with baseline survey. I am interested to find significant difference between baseline and endline. One of sample questions is given below. Baseline and endline sample for this question is different. This question had 5 possible answers. Multiple answers were possible. Now I want to analyse if the there is a significant difference between baseline and endline use of different sources to keep home warm.

What do you do to keep your home warm?
[image]

What I have done is use z-test to find two sample proportion difference using z-test using this (http://epitools.ausvet.com.au/content.php?page=z-test-2) resource.

I want to know is this a correct way? if not what else coudld be a correct alternative?

Comment: Are you after a single test for differences, or do you want to test each source for a difference?  ... incidentally, the endline numbers can't be right - you have "312" for  "Burn gas", which is more than 100%  of the N=250 you have in the endline group.

Comment: @ Glen_b, this is just a dummy table, so you are right, there may be mistakes. I didnät past the original data. I am interested in significant difference in each source seperatly.

Answer (score 1):

Each of the by-source comparisons could be done as a two sample proportions test (for which you could indeed consider the z-test you mention), but if those made up numbers are typical, some of your expected values might be too small for the normal approximation to the test statistic to work well.

You might (but on the other hand might not) also want to consider whether you want to put some control on the familywise type I error rate. [The tests also won't be (quite) independent - indeed they'd typically be expected to be negatively dependent, since there will be some tendency to substitute one for another.]

Comment: Glen-b: you are right actuall data do behave like that. I have some responses less than five, which means the assumptions of z test is not fullfilled. Now, I am not sure what alternatives I have. X square test may be used as well. But I am not sure, wether I have to use it seperately for each source to find sig. difference (2 x 2 table). It would mean repeating this test five times for the above question. Or is there any other way?

Comment: It's not the size of the *response* being less than five that's an issue, but the expected number under the null hypothesis. This depends on the other three numbers in the proporton comparison as well. A chi-square test has the same sample size issue. I think it's possible to organize this as 5 separate tests or as one combined test. If done as one combined test, I think you can do post hoc comparisons.